# Force smaller screen to scale to a larger resolution?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

My site requires at least 720px width. Iphone 6 appears a resolution of 1334x750 but their browser reports 667px. Samsung S5 supposedly is 1080x1920 but the browser reports 640.

I know the screen can handle the details but I'm not sure how to get a larger resolution. I need 720px to be the minimum width so what do I do to have phones <720px to scale correctly? By scale I mean show all 720px without any scrolling

Comment: Not sure what exactly you aim for but maybe this provides a good basis for some research: https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with this in the head code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

then add media queries to you css sheet that support all current devices 
http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/JKdOaj

Comment: I'm confused. Googling around I figured out how to test for landscape orientation but now I can't figure out how to lock it to 720px width. I know how to detect it but I have two 360px images and I need both to be on screen side by side (testing for real site).

Comment: have you made a test page and added that to your test css page?

Comment: I did and I'm unsure what happened. It looked like all it did was show media queries in chrome but page looks exactly the same. I believe I'm suppose to put in styles for each device. I'm not sure how to say scale a 720px width page to this device width

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or ALL the code that you have tried?

Comment: I'm testing using chrome. My phone is >800px so I have no idea if I fixed it using that https://jsfiddle.net/y3zmmLek/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want your contents width to be scaled down to the width of the viewport. This is usually done automatically unless the code contains the following line in the `head` section of the page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So if this *is* in your code, *remove it*. (But note that you make your page non-responsive that way, which is rather unusual nowadays!)

Concerning your observations in regard to device pixels: This has to do with "pixel density" which is important for the better display/sharpness of text (fonts) and vector graphics, as well as images if high-resolution images are supplied to the browser. For example the iPhone 6 actually has a height of 1334 physical pixels (ratio 1:2), which is however treated as 667px when it comes to CSS pixel units.

Comment: When I remove it, it seems to be fixed at 980. How do I make it 720?

Comment: It should be scaled down automatically if this line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Input this in .css code before using the code design

@media only screen and (min-width:720px) 
and (max-width:1336px) and (min-resolution

Comment: Also, *test* your code on a variety of screen sizes! You might need to embed assets that are as-big or bigger than any screen *(and hope that puny hardware can do a decent job of scaling it down),* or, you might need to bundle multiple assets of different dimensions. "It can get ugly," but also, "unpredictable." The display is one of the most expensive components of a portable device, and *plenty* of corners were cut by engineers who were striving to make "a cheaper phone to sell in a grocery store."